# Error number meaning in USB driver failure, PS2 keyboard

Tags: drivers, usb, keyboard

I'm trying to use an old PS2 keyboard (a nice mechanical one) with a USB converter. After connecting the device the driver fails. The device is being detected as Barcode reader but in Windows is working fine, (do you think that is ok for the converter to be detected as a Barcode reader?, that is basically a keyboard).

```
# lsusb
...
 Bus 001 Device 044: ID 13ba:0018 PCPlay Barcode PCP-BCG4209
...
#dmesg
...
[22164.756069] usb 1-2.4: New USB device found, idVendor=13ba, idProduct=0018
[22164.756073] usb 1-2.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[22164.756301] usb 1-2.4: no configuration chosen from 0 choices
[22178.179941] usb 1-2.4: USB disconnect, device number 43
[22179.965941] usb 1-2.4: new low-speed USB device number 44 using xhci_hcd
[22180.113937] usb 1-2.4: string descriptor 0 read error: -32
[22180.113947] usb 1-2.4: New USB device found, idVendor=13ba, idProduct=0018
[22180.113951] usb 1-2.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[22180.116927] usb 1-2.4: can't set config #1, error -32
```

Where can I find the -32 error meaning of the driver? Notice that the driver was not able to read the string descriptor before the configuration failure. Thanks!